# How to display 2 intensity histograms of images side-by-side in Python

Tags: python, histogram

I am creating 2 histograms and trying to display them side by side. I have tried displaying them next to each other as is, tried converting the histograms into png files and concatenate them that way, and I've tried using plt.savefig() but I don't think I've implemented any of these approaches correctly... I've had no luck. This is what my related functions look like:

```
def intensity_histogram(img):
    img = io.imread(img)
    ax = plt.hist(img.ravel(), bins = 256, histtype = 'step', color = 'b')
    plt.title('Histogram')
    # plt.show()

def main():
    img1 = intensity_histogram('html/images/lenna.png')
    img2 = intensity_histogram('html/images/lenna_gray.png')
```

Maybe I have to make a for loop in my intensity_histogram? But I wouldn't know what that would look like (not very familiar with Python). By uncommenting my plt.show(), my code displays them, but it first displays the histogram for img1, then I have to close the window, then it'd open up the histogram for the second one automatically. Please help me display the two histograms that I've created to by side-by-side instead. If there's also a way to have separate titles for these, please let me know as well.

Comment: you should look into subplots

Comment: @ChristianSloper This seems like a good approach but the examples I've seen online are hard for me to apply to my case. I've mostly seen cases of creating random histograms (arrays of numbers, not images) within their histogram(). But I would need to make "subplots" for the 2 histograms of images I made. I'm not sure what this would look like.